# Making I/O bound operation asynchronous

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, exceldatareader

I am developing a web application that will read Excel files and make some validation.

I use `ExcelDataReader` library, which lacks async methods.

`Read()` method takes care of reading the next rows in a sheet, so it is mostly I/O bound (it just advances the stream to a certain position, so data from the row is available).

To increase my throughput, I wrapped it in `Task.Run`, like:

```
await Task.Run(() => excelDataReader.Read());
```

From benchmarks I can see it executes faster (or at least no longer) than regular synchronous call `excelDataReader.Read()`

From posts I read I see `Task.Run` is recommended only in UI scenarios, when we need to unblock the UI thread.

So, the question is does it make sense to wrap I/O bound operations in `Task.Run` ?

Or am I missing something?

### EDIT:

benchmark results

[image]

So the second question would be - if my approach is just wrong, why it performs better?

### ANOTHER EDIT:

Below is benchmark code that showed that asynchronous version is much faster:

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using ExcelDataReader;
using System.Text;

namespace ExcelDataReaderTests;

public class ExcelDataReaderTester
{
    private const string DirectoryWithManyBigExcelFiles = @"Directory With Many Big Excel Files";

    [Benchmark]
    public async Task TestAsync()
    {
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

        var directory = Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryWithManyBigExcelFiles);

        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var file in directory)
        {
            tasks.Add(UseExcelDataReadAsync(file));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Test()
    {
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        var directory = Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryWithManyBigExcelFiles);

        foreach (var file in directory)
        {
            UseExcelDataRead(file);
        }
    }

    private static void UseExcelDataRead(string filePath)
    {
        var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
        var excelDataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(fileStream);

        while (excelDataReader.Read())
        {
            var x = excelDataReader.GetFieldType(0);
        }
    }

    private static async Task UseExcelDataReadAsync(string filePath)
    {
        var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
        var excelDataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(fileStream);

        while (await Task.Run(() => excelDataReader.Read()))
        {
            var x = excelDataReader.GetFieldType(0);
        }
    }
}
```

And the benchmark are run with:

```
BenchmarkRunner.Run(typeof(ExcelDataReaderTester).Assembly);
```

I am using [BechmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html) for benchmarking.

Comment: There's no IO involved in this code. If you use ExcelDataReader, the data is already loaded in memory. ADO.NET classes already have async operations where this makes sense

Comment: Important reading: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)

Answer (score 2):

ExcelDataReader loads all data in memory so it makes no sense to provide asynchronous methods. The `xlsx` format is a ZIP package containing XML files which can't be read line by line. There's no IO involved in `ExcelDataReader.Read`.

The real IO is performed by `CreateReader`. Unfortunately there's no `CreateReaderAsync` and [no plan to add this yet](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/issues/402)

In general, pushing an IO operation to another thread won't make it faster.

In a desktop application, if you want to process the contents of an Excel file without blocking the UI thread, put the entire processing code into a method and call it with `Task.Run`. For more complex processing you can use eg DataFlow or Channels to execute multiple processing steps in the background.

In a web application though, each request is server by a different ThreadPool thread. There's no UI thread to block. `await Task.Run(...)` simply moves execution from one ThreadPool thread to another.

Comment: Ok, did not see the source code, it was just my assumption, thanks for clarification. But i am surprised, that async is anyway faster than synchronous by 33% (see my edit). It is confusing, that's why my question arised.

Comment: What was the actual benchmark code? In any case async IO means that no thread is used to perform IO. It's not the same as running the IO process in another thread.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but finally I managed to add benchmark code. As I understand your answer and agree with it, I don't seem understand the matter well enough and now I am curious what is the reason the fake async performs better.

Comment: You didn't benchmark the asynchronous `Read`, you benchmarked parallel loading of multiple files vs sequential loading. If you used `Task.Run` in the `UseExcelDataRead` you'd get the same results. The benchmark you need to run is for a *single* file, with or without `Task.Run`

Answer (score 1):

You technically do **multithreaded programming** by wrapping the synchronous code with `Task.Run`.

```
await Task.Run(() => excelDataReader.Read());
```

But you won't do **asynchronous programming** with this. It may look like you do, but you actually don't because what's inside is not an `I/O` operation.

The `excelDataReader.Read()` will be simply picked up by a threadpool thread, and the thread will **synchronously** run the action, which means it is going to be **blocked**. If you receive many requests enough to saturate all your threadpool threads, what you're going to suffer is `Thread Starvation`. Your server won't be responsive in the end.

And I want to add two comments on this statement. *From posts I read I see Task.Run is recommended only in UI scenarios, when we need to unblock the UI thread.*

1. The general purpose of `Task.Run` is not for unblocking the UI thread. It is recommended for `CPU Bound` job or something you can fire&forget.
2. Where `I/O` job involved, you can avoid blocking the UI thread by introducing `async/await`.

You need to update your code that outputs the benchmark result. Async alone doesn't increase the performance, instead it increases thread availability.

Comment: *"`Task.Run` is not for unblocking the UI thread."* -- Why do you think it's not? Apparently the `Task.Run` works pretty well at keeping the UI responsive. Where did you get this advice from?

Comment: Yeah it will definitely work and it can be used in that way for sure, but I just wanted to point out that the general purpose of `Task.Run` is not for unblocking UI thread. I just realized that my comment could sound like `Task.Run` cannot be used to unblock UI thread, which I didn’t mean it at all.

Comment: I explicitly said _It is not for unblocking UI thread_ because @micha-turczyn mentioned that `Task.Run` is **only** recommended in UI scenario. I think I should change the statement a bit to prevent further confusions for future readers anyway.

Comment: @hina10531 I explain in my answer that ExcelDataReader unzips and loads the entire Excel sheet in memory, so there's not much for `Read` to do in the background. The operation that would benefit from `Task.Run` is `CreateReader`. The OP's benchmark is measuring the wrong thing too